# Segmentation Fault Generating RSA Key Using OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to generate RSA keys using OpenSSL with the following function:

```
RSA *genRSA() {
  clear();
  mvprintw(0, 0, "Generating RSA key...\n");
  RAND_load_file("/dev/random", 4096);
  BIGNUM *e = BN_new();
  BN_set_word(e, RSA_F4);
  RSA *rsa;
  while (getch() != '\n'); // the program does reach this point
  if (!RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 4096, e, 0)) { // seg fault must occur on this line
    while (getch() != '\n'); // never gets here
    printw("ERROR: Failed to create RSA key\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  while (getch() != '\n'); // or here
  BN_free(e);
  if (!RSA_check_key(rsa)) {
    printw("ERROR: Key failed validation\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  printw("Key generation completed successfully\n");
  return rsa;
}
```

I'm not receiving any compiler warnings other than some deprecated on OS X ones (could that be causing an issue?). Why am I getting a seg fault?

Comment: If you're certain it's faulting in the RSA_generate_key_ex() function, then its likely your input parameters. Verify that each one is as expected for the function.

Comment: This could be a problem, too: `RAND_load_file("/dev/random", 4096);`. You are asking for bytes, not bits. And a lot of them. It could deplete the device and you could block a long time. To achieve the equivalent of 4096-bit key, you need about 140-bit security level. 140/8 = 17.5 bytes: `RAND_load_file("/dev/random", 18);`.

Comment: @jww Fortunatly for me it didn't take too long, but I will take your suggestion into thought.

Comment: @cabellicar123 - in that case, `RAND_load_file("/dev/random", 4096);` probably failed. You should check the return value and fall back to `"/dev/urandom"`.

Comment: @jww Ok. Will do. Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the library you're using, this is incorrect:

```
RSA *rsa;
while (getch() != '\n'); // the program does reach this point
  if (!RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 4096, e, 0))
```

You are calling `RSA_generate_key_ex` with an uninitialized pointer `rsa`.  There is no way that `RSA_generate_key_ex` function is going to be able to do anything with it except attempt to use it and as you see, crash.

So read the docs on that function as to what the first parameter is supposed to be.  Maybe it should be this:

```
RSA rsa;
while (getch() != '\n'); // the program does reach this point
  if (!RSA_generate_key_ex(&rsa, 4096, e, 0))
```

If this is the case, then you need to change your return type to `RSA` and not `RSA*` (I'm assuming that `RSA` is a struct or typedef of a type that can be returned safely by value).

Comment: I figured out I needed to first initialize RSA by changing the line to `RSA *rsa = RSA_new();`. Thanks for the help!